# Mobile First Auto-update fails in iOS devices while changing the Server URL at run time

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-studio, mobilefirst-appcenter

I'm working on an IBM MobileFirst Platform 7.1 project where we have many remote servers say, **Dev, Test** etc. The requirement was to change the servers at run time so that we would not be required to build and distribute multiple apps.

I followed the Official [IBM tutorial](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2015/02/02/changing-server-url-runtime/).

Here is the code I use to connect to the server after the server is changed.

```
WL.Client.connect({onSuccess: function(){
        WL.SimpleDialog.show(
                "Connection Success", "Successfully connected to the server URL. Your app will reload once you press OK",  
                [{text: "OK", handler: function() {WL.Client.reloadApp();}}]
        );
    }, onFailure: function(error) {
        WL.SimpleDialog.show(
                "Connection Falied", error.status +" "+error.errorCode + " : " + error.errorMsg,  
                [{text: "Close", handler: function() {}}]
        );
    }});
```

It works perfectly fine in Android. But, in iOS devices, the server gets changed and gets connected to the new server. When the Auto-update runs in order to fetch the new code from the changed server, it gets **Stuck indefinitely**

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this only if you change the server url? If you do not change the server URL at runtime, and connect directly to the new server, does it work?

Comment: @VivinK Yes. It does work when I directly connect to the new server without changing it at run time.

Comment: And by auto-update you mean direct update?

Comment: Yes. Direct update from the mobile first server.